# Projected Light Cookie Has Its Texture Edges Instead of Spotlight Circular Edges

Tags: unity, lighting

The projected light of Unity Spotlight on a flat surface is almost a circle:

[image]

But when I add this light cookie:

[image]

It renders the following projection:

[image]

I expect the projected image takes the spotlight's edges.

Unity version: 2017.4.11f1

light source settings:

[image]

Light cookie settings:

[image]

Please note that I've already added black padding to the light cookie.

Comment: It looks like you could just paint a black circular frame into your cookie texture to achieve this look. Have you had any trouble implementing that approach?

Comment: @DMGregory. I could do that but I would count that as a 'workaround'.